# How to pass data to the markup of a custom component?

Tags: angular7

I have a custom component that allows for editing a user. It displays a dialog which can be fed an existing user. Or not. It has the markup:

```
<button mat-button (click)="openUserDialog()">Edit</button>
```

and the controller:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-edit',
  templateUrl: './user-edit.component.html',
})
export class UserEditComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() existingUser: User;
  @Output() userEditedEvent: EventEmitter<User> = new EventEmitter<User>();

  userDialogRef: MatDialogRef<UserDialogComponent>;

  constructor(
    private matDialog: MatDialog,
    private userService: UserService
  ) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
  }

  openUserDialog() {
    this.userDialogRef = this.matDialog.open(UserDialogComponent, {
      hasBackdrop: false,
      data: {
        user: this.existingUser
      }
    });

    this.userDialogRef
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe(user => {
        // TODO validate the edited user
        if (user) {
          if (this.existingUser) {
            user.id = this.existingUser.id;
            this.userService.fullUpdate(user)
              .subscribe(updatedUser => {
                this.userEditedEvent.emit(updatedUser);
                // TODO Add a hint that the user has been added
              });
          } else {
            this.userService.add(user)
              .subscribe(addedUser => {
                this.userEditedEvent.emit(addedUser);
                // TODO Add a hint that the user has been updated
              });
          }
        }
      });
  }

}
```

The component is then being used in the users list page, once on top of the list to add a new user, with the markup:

```
<app-user-edit (userEditedEvent)="refreshList($event)"></app-user-edit>
```

and on each row of the list to edit the user, with the markup:

```
<app-user-edit [existingUser]="user" (userEditedEvent)="refreshList($event)"></app-user-edit>
```

The trouble is that the view displays the Edit label both to add and to edit a user.

How could I have a custom Add label on top of the list, and another Update label for each user ?

I feel like I may have overengineered the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another @Input parameter say **label** and pass the value of the label from the mark up.

```
export class UserEditComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() existingUser: User;
  @Input() label: string = "Edit" // set default to EDIT. If preferred can initialised to empty.
```

Mark up for ADD:

```
<app-user-edit (userEditedEvent)="refreshList($event)" label="ADD"></app-user-edit>
```

Mark up for EDIT:

```
<app-user-edit [existingUser]="user" (userEditedEvent)="refreshList($event)" label="EDIT"></app-user-edit>
```

Also, bind parameter label in view where it needs to be shown.

Comment: When I specify the attribute `label]="Add"` no label is displayed. When I specify the attribute `label]="Add me"` the browser console shows the runtime error: `Unexpected token 'me' at column 5 in [Add me]`.

Comment: sorry, remove the square brackets.Have edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Interesting.. why some `@Input` member variables need the bracket in the markup, while others don't ?

Comment: [] brackets make Angular evaluate that as an expression. You can still use []  but will have to pass the value like [label]=" 'Add me' ". Hope that helps.